# Binary red black tree, best way to walk back to root?

Tags: c#, algorithm, tree

I'm in the processes of building a binary red black tree. One issue I'm seeing is in rotations and moving backwards to parent nodes to find black red violations after doing rotations. I don't want to search the tree again for the last node, so I have started using a back pointer for each node. Not sure if my brain is fried and I'm not thinking about this right, but if I have to walk the tree again to find:

```
if (node.left or .right = current) [which gives me a grandparent]
```

aren't I really increasing my insertion time to worst case `Log2(n^n-1)+C'

c being whatever constant time equals.

I'd imagine though, that the back pointer is much cheaper. even though a little tricky to reconnect on rotations, although not that hard. So essentially wouldn't I just be adding constant time vs increasing my time exponentially?

Comment: Can't you just have a `node.Parent` property and then just recursively grab each parent node till its `null` (which would mean it was the root node)

Comment: So if node parent = current before moving left or right, which would have to be done recursively. Once violation has occurred pop the stack kind of thing and move up to root if needed, making needed changes along the way. I get the idea, but not visualizing how to handle that recursive call, not to mention what that could do the memory heap.

Comment: Draw a diagram on paper.  Do the steps on the paper to visualize the process.  It saves a lot of headaches.  I did this years ago and ended up with more punch cards in the circular bin than in my final code.  Good Luck.

Comment: That was harder than I anticipated, but finished checking each case and everything balances correctly, The code below is messy but it works. I'll rewrite a more generic API form myself once I get everything up and running. Funny though, I've had a lot of trouble in the past with tail recursive calls, now it doesn't seem that hard.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.ComponentModel;
using System.Data;
using System.Drawing;

using System.Linq;

using System.Text;

using System.Windows.Forms;

namespace RedBlackTree
{
    class RBTree
     {
        public class node {

       public  node right, left, next, back,last;//for traversing the   


          public int id;//for regular implementation
            int day, month, year;//for root @ weeks
            int hour, min;//for shipment times
            byte amPm = 0;//for shipment times
           public char color = 'r';//color of node
           public Object data;//needed data of node

        }
        Queue<node> q = new Queue<node>();
        node head, tail, isRoot;
        node weeks, soNum, custByName;//main roots when customized

        node root = null;//for regular insert
       static Boolean allIsoff = false; 
        //regular insert 
        public void printRoot() {
            MessageBox.Show(root.id.ToString());
        }
        public void insert(int key, Object info) {
            allIsoff = false;
            node child = new node();
            child.id = key;
            child.data = info;
           if(root == null){
               root = child;
               child.color = 'b';
               return;
           }//end root is null

          //setup parent and grandParent nodes
           node parent = null;
           node grandParent = null;
            node GGparent = null;
           addNode(child, root, parent, grandParent,GGparent);


        }//end insert


        //for regular insertion
        private void addNode(node child, node current, node parent, node grandParent,node greatGparent){
           Boolean isTrue = false;//for child and current
           Boolean theRest = false;//for current and parent
           if(current.id == child.id){
               current.data = child.data;
               return;
           }
           if(current.id > child.id ){//going left
               if (current.left == null)
               {

                   current.left = child;//add child to the left
                   isTrue = isRed(current,child);

               }
               else {//continue left 
                   addNode(child, current.left, current, parent,grandParent);


               }


           }//end going left
           else if (current.id < child.id) {//going right 
               if (current.right == null)
               {
                   current.right = child;
                   isTrue = isRed(current, child);
               }
               else {//continue right 
                   addNode(child, current.right, current, parent,grandParent);
               }

           }//end going right

           if (isTrue == false && allIsoff == false)//then check current and parent
           {

               theRest = isRed(current, parent);
               System.Diagnostics.Debug.WriteLine(current.id+" "+parent.id);
           }//end isTrue

           if(isTrue || theRest){//if there is a red clash

                if (isTrue) {
                    if (checkUncle(current, parent))
                    {
                        repaint(parent);
                        isTrue = false;
                    }
                    else
                    {
                        //rotate
                        if (current.id > child.id)
                        {//left of parent
                            if (parent != null)
                            {
                                if (parent.left == current)//P is left of Grandparent
                                {

                                    System.Diagnostics.Debug.WriteLine("T1.A");
                                    current.color = 'b';
                                    parent.color = 'r';
                                    rotateRight(current, parent, grandParent);
                                    allIsoff = true;
                                    return;

                                }
                                else
                                {//P is Right of Grandparent
                                    System.Diagnostics.Debug.WriteLine("T1.B");
                                    child.color = 'b';
                                    parent.color = 'r';
                                    rotateRight(child,current,parent);
                                    rotateLeft(parent,child,grandParent);
                                    allIsoff = true;
                                    return;
                                }


                            }//endif P != null




                        }//end if current > child
                        else {//child is right of current


                            if (parent.left == current)//parent is left of grandparent
                            {
                                System.Diagnostics.Debug.WriteLine("T1.C");
                                rotateLeft(current, child, parent);
                                child.color = 'b';
                                parent.color = 'r';
                                rotateRight(child, parent, grandParent);
                                allIsoff = true;
                                return;

                            }
                            else
                            { //parent is right of grandparent
                                System.Diagnostics.Debug.WriteLine("T1.D");
                                rotateLeft(parent, current, grandParent);
                                current.color = 'b';
                                parent.color = 'r';
                                allIsoff = true;
                                return;
                            }




                        }//end else


                    }//END ELSE


                }//end isTure
                else if (theRest) {

                    if (checkUncle(parent, grandParent))
                    {
                        repaint(grandParent);
                        theRest = false;
                    }
                    else
                    {
                        //rotate
                        if (parent.id > current.id)
                        { //left of parent

                            if (grandParent != null)
                            {
                                if (grandParent.left == parent)//P is left of Grandparent
                                {

                                    System.Diagnostics.Debug.WriteLine("T2.A");
                                    grandParent.color = 'r';
                                    parent.color = 'b';
                                    rotateRight(parent,grandParent,greatGparent);
                                    allIsoff = true;
                                    return;

                                }
                                else
                                {//P is Right of Grandparent
                                    System.Diagnostics.Debug.WriteLine("T2.B");
                                    rotateRight(current, parent, grandParent);
                                    grandParent.color = 'r';
                                    current.color = 'b';
                                    rotateLeft(grandParent, current, greatGparent);
                                    allIsoff = true;
                                    return;
                                }
                            }//what if grandParent is null????????
                            else {
                                if (parent.right.color == 'b')//code should never execute
                                {
                                    System.Diagnostics.Debug.WriteLine("T2.C"); 
                                    current.color = 'b';
                                    rotateRight(current,parent,null);
                                    allIsoff = true;
                                    return;
                                }


                            }//end else for root rotation

                        }
                        else {//right of parent 
                            if (grandParent != null)
                            {
                                if (grandParent.left == parent)//P is left of Grandparent
                                {

                                    System.Diagnostics.Debug.WriteLine("T2.D");
                                    rotateLeft(parent,current,greatGparent);
                                    current.color = 'b';
                                    grandParent.color = 'r';
                                    rotateRight(current,grandParent,greatGparent);
                                    allIsoff = true;
                                    return;

                                }
                                else
                                {//P is Right of Grandparent
                                    System.Diagnostics.Debug.WriteLine("T2.E");
                                    rotateLeft(grandParent,parent,greatGparent);
                                    grandParent.color = 'r';
                                    parent.color = 'b';
                                    allIsoff = true;
                                    return;
                                }
                            }//what if grandParent is null????????
                            else
                            {
                                if (parent.left.color == 'b')//CODE SHOULD NEVER EXECUTE
                                {
                                    System.Diagnostics.Debug.WriteLine("T2.F");
                                    current.color = 'b';
                                    rotateLeft(parent,current,null);
                                    allIsoff = true;
                                    return;
                                }


                            }//end else for root rotation


                        }

                    }//END ELSE

                }

            }//end red clash check


        }//end addNode

        public void repaint(node grandparent) {
            grandparent.right.color = 'b';
            grandparent.left.color = 'b';
            grandparent.color = 'r';
            if (grandparent == root) {
                grandparent.color = 'b';

            }
        }

        public Boolean checkUncle(node parent, node grandparent) {
            if (parent != null) {
                if (grandparent != null) {
                    if (grandparent.left == parent)
                    {
                        if (grandparent.right != null)
                        {
                            if (grandparent.right.color.Equals('r'))
                            {
                                return true;

                            }
                        }

                    }
                    else {
                        if (grandparent.left != null)
                        {
                            if (grandparent.left.color.Equals('r'))
                            {
                                return true;

                            }
                        }

                    }


                }

            }
            return false;
        }//end check uncle

        public Boolean isRed(node a, node b) {
            if (a != null)
            {
                if (a.color.Equals('r'))
                {
                    if (b != null)
                    {
                        if (b.color.Equals('r'))
                        {
                            return true;
                        }
                    }
                }
            }
            return false;

        }


        //inorder traversal for testing
        String inorder = "";

        public void doTraversal() {

            inorderT(root);
        }
        public void inorderT(node current) {

            if (current != null)
            {
                inorder += current.id.ToString() + "(" + current.color.ToString() + "),";

                inorderT(current.left);
                inorderT(current.right);
            }


        }//end inorderT

        public String getInorder() {
            return inorder;
        }

        public void resetInorder() {
            inorder = "";
        }

        public void clearTree() {
            root = null;
        }

        //end methods for inorder traversal for testing
        public void breadthFirst() {




        }



        public void rotateLeft(node p, node q, node grand) {
            if (grand != null)
            {

                System.Diagnostics.Debug.WriteLine("hereRotateLeft !null");

                p.right = q.left;

                q.left = p;
                if (grand.right == p)
                {
                    grand.right = q;

                }
                else { grand.left = q; }
            }
            else {
                System.Diagnostics.Debug.WriteLine("hereRotateLeft else");

                p.right = q.left;

                q.left = p;
                root = q;

            }


        }//end left rotation

        public void rotateRight(node p, node q, node grand)
        {
            if (grand != null)
            {
                System.Diagnostics.Debug.WriteLine("hereRotateRight not null");


                q.left = p.right;

                p.right = q;
                if (grand.right == q)
                {
                    grand.right = p;

                }
                else { grand.left = p; }
            }
            else
            {
                System.Diagnostics.Debug.WriteLine("hereRotateRight else");
                q.left = p.right;

                p.right = q;
                root = p;
            }


        }//end left rotation



        public void addLotForward() {
            for (int l = 0; l < 12; l++ )
            {
                insert(l, "");

            }
        }
      // Queue<node> q = new Queue<node>();

        //following code is for testing, breadth first search
        int[] arr = new int[]{1,2,4,8,16,32,64,128,256,512,1024,2048,4096,8192,16384};
        int i =0;
        int b = 0;
        int w = 0;
        int keeper = 0;
        public void BFS()
        {


            q.Enqueue(root);
            while (q.Count > 0)
            {

                node n = q.Dequeue();

                if (i == arr[b])
                {

                    System.Diagnostics.Debug.Write("\r\n"+"("+n.id+""+n.color+")"); 
                    b++;
                    i =0 ;
                }
                else {

                    System.Diagnostics.Debug.Write("(" + n.id + "" + n.color + ")"); 

                }
                i++;


                if (n.id != -1)
                {
                    w = 0;


                    if (n.left != null)
                    {

                        q.Enqueue(n.left);
                    }
                    else
                    {
                        node c = new node();
                        c.id = -1;
                        c.color = 'b';
                        q.Enqueue(c);
                    }

                    if (n.right != null)
                    {

                        q.Enqueue(n.right);
                    }
                    else
                    {
                        node c = new node();
                        c.id = -1;
                        c.color = 'b';
                        q.Enqueue(c);

                    }
                }
                else {
                    w++;
                    node c = new node();
                    c.id = -1;
                    c.color = 'b';
                    q.Enqueue(c);
                    if (w == arr[b])
                    {

                        break;
                    }
                }



            }
            q.Clear();
            w = 0;
            i = 0;
            b = 0;
            System.Diagnostics.Debug.Write("\r\n");
            return;
        }

    }//end main class
}
```